# When running "docker-compose up" I get the following message "services must be a mapping"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

docker-compose.yml contains:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
build: .
web:
ports:
  - "8000:8000"
command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
volumes:
  - .:/code
```

Comment: YAML is very sensitive to indentation.  Can you [edit] the question to make sure it's presented properly?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like everything after `service:` should be indented. Also, the service name should be before the `build: .` instruction. And it is best practice to use an array for the `command` when spaces are involved.

Try

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

Comment: I tried:version: "3.9"
services:
  build: .
  web:
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code and now when I run docker-compose up, I get services.command must be a mapping

Comment: I copied your code and it works. Thanks very much.